# How to print column or row spanned datagridview in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having trouble wit print data grid view having spanned cells. I followed below article on code project.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34037/DataGridVewTextBoxCell-with-Span-Behaviour

I want to print like exactly the same as its displaying the grid view. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The article provides source code, did you download the source code. Assuming it works you should be able to download, open the project and debug it to see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you actually print the `DataGridView`. Here are some examples:

HTML (the attribute has same name - `ColumnSpan`):

```
...
<td colspan=""" + MyCell.ColumnSpan + """>My spanned text</td>
...
```

Printing it into a table in PDF document using `MigraDoc`, here the attribute is called `MergeRight`:

```
...
TableD5.Rows(0).Cells(0).MergeRight = MyCell.ColumnSpan;
...
```

The `MyCell.ColumnSpan` is an object from your link, the article *[DataGridVewTextBoxCell with Span Behaviour](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34037/DataGridVewTextBoxCell-with-Span-Behaviour)*